# Cannot create a row of size 8768 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060

Tags: java, eclipse, sql-server-2008, jboss5.x

I am getting this error when I put a compiled JAVA code in JBoss 5.0. When I run directly from eclipse it completely works fine.

The database is SQL Server 2008 and we are using Hibernate to query the database.

I suspect that there is some setting in JBoss which might solve this issue.

Looking for a solution to this.

Comment: Step 1- accept answers to  your other questions.  Step 2 - get productive feedback on your new ones.  Step 3 - Profit

Answer (score 4):

The maximum bytes per row for SQL Server 2008 is 8,060 for 32 and 64 bit architectures. [See here for all capacity specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx).

This means that an attempt to create a row with more data than 8,060 bytes will fail. If you don't get a failure on this type of operation it means that the error got swallowed somewhere along the way.

**or**

You might not actually be running a test on the same type of data (size & type) our of JBoss as you do from Eclipse.

Comment: I am not getting any exceptions while I run from JBoss and things work fine.

Comment: @KuntalShah: You need to make sure that when running from JBoss that you're running the same test on the same kind of data as your other scenario. There is no way to get more data into a SQL Server row than will be allowed... Make sure that you're comparing apples to apples.

Comment: You are right, I am comparing apples to apples only. I face issue in the same situation.